# Infinite series, switched notation, locally finite family of series

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, polynomials, formal-power-series, monomial-function

I'm reading *Lothaire: Combinatorics on words* the infinite series part and I have a small problem:
I do not understand what is on the page 12
$(\sigma^i)_{i\geq 0}$
and why is
$\langle \sigma^i,w\rangle =0$ for $i\geq |w|+1$ ?

In the text they define $\sigma_i$ but not $\sigma^i$. One can think that $\sigma^i$ is just the $i-$th power monomial, but still I do not follow the above implication that
$\langle \sigma^i,w\rangle =0$ for $i\geq |w|+1$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: $(\sigma^{i})_{i \geq 0}$ is a [sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence). A sequence can be seen as a generalisation of the concept of "ordered pair" to any number of elements, including a countable infinity of elements. The purpose of this sequence is to present an infinite number of entries in an order: its zeroth entry is $\sigma^0$, its first entry is $\sigma$, its second entry is $\sigma^2$ and so on. In general, its ith entry is $\sigma^{i}$ where $i$ is an integer $\geq 0$.

Comment: About $\sigma^i$: I haven't read this text but, in the pages you included, the author defines the product $\sigma\tau$ of series $\sigma$ and $\tau$. Then $\sigma^i$ is just the product of $i$ copies of $\sigma$, e.g. $\sigma^3$ is $\sigma\sigma\sigma$. (The bracketing of $\sigma\sigma\sigma$ doesn't matter in this case because product is associative.) I hope this helps.

Comment: @PenelopeClairmont Right. And how it follows $\langle \sigma^i,w\rangle =0$ for $i\geq |w|+1$ from $\langle\sigma,1\rangle=0$ ?